# JavaScript to stream video files

Tags: javascript, video, api

Is there a JavaScript API for streaming WMV/AVI/MOV files?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with no JavaScript; just use the solution described here: http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/embedded-windows-media-player-t70151.html. Basically you'd create an ASX playlist file pointing to your media, then set the URL of the OBJECT tag's `PARAM` to the ASX file.

Note that WMV might require an [additional plugin for Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20Windows%20Media%20Player%20plugin%20with%20Firefox) and other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

[JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) is an open source video / audio player for the Web. It supports playback of any format the Adobe Flash Player and HTML5 browsers can handle (FLV, H.264, MP4, VP8, WebM, MP3, AAC, JPG, PNG and GIF). It also supports various streaming and playlist formats (including RMTP, HTTP, live streaming and more) and a wide range of playback options.

It has a [JS API](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at http://flowplayer.org/

JS API: http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Flowplayer. http://flowplayer.org/
It provides number of other support options as well like iOS & Android device support, skin customization, integration with Carousals, sharing on social sites etc.

JS API: http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html

Comment: Flowplayer has already been suggested in another answer. Once you have enough reputation then you can leave comments on other answers. ...Or you can edit other answers (even with 1 rep) if you have relevant additional information.

Answer (score -2):

try this hope it helps
http://www.pcurtis.com/media.htm

Comment: That page is super old. You shouldn't be using `embed` for embedding videos anymore. You can now do it with just the `object` element.